# How To Check HTTPD Directory Enforcement?

Tags: apache-2.4, httpd, fedora

Fedora 29 with HTTPD Apache 2.4

By default access to the server's directory system is protected by this entry in httpd.conf:

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>
```

...and is overwritten on a per-directory basis with further `<directory>` rules; so I have virtual host blocks as shown below and I would like to run a test to ensure that `<Directory "/">` is not allowing access outside of the DocumentRoot. How do I do this?

```
<VirtualHost insurgent.info:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/httpd/insurgent"
    ServerName insurgent.info

<Directory "/"> 
    Require all granted
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks IncludesNoExec
    AllowOverride None
    XBitHack Full
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/httpd/insurgent/.cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule alias_module>
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/httpd/insurgent/.cgi-bin/"
</IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Directory points to a directory in your filesystem, so in virtualhosts you specify

```
<Directory /var/httpd/insurgent>
Require all granted
#other directives 
</Directory>
```

to allow access to your documentroot.

The official documentation is very specific with this:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#directory

The entry pointing to /, should only be in server config context

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>
```

and is really needed to forbid access anywhere else, but don't use it in Virtualhosts!

Comment: Thanks, - I have all that; but what I was wanting to know was whether there was some way in which I could verify whether or not the entries were actually working in a real-world context as part of hardening the server against attacks. - It is all well and good looking at looking at the code and saying "yes, in theory everything is contained" but it is useless unless you can actually confirm that.